# How to set an attribute as percentage in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, percentage

I am unable to set css attribute `{left: $numberEquivalentToPercent}` in jQuery

```
var targets = $('.parallax__layer__cell');
var i = 1;
for(i = 1; i <= targets.length; i++)
{
  if (targets.parents('.parallax__layer--bg').length) {
//apply to only those element that have a parent having class "parallax__layer--bg"
    targets.eq(i).css('left', toString(60*i)+  "%");
  }
}
```

The above code(in JS) is expected to produce the same effect as below(in CSS)

```
.parallax__layer__cell:nth-child(1) { left: 0%; }
.parallax__layer__cell:nth-child(2) { left: 60%; }
.parallax__layer__cell:nth-child(3) { left: 120%; }
.parallax__layer__cell:nth-child(4) { left: 180%; }
.parallax__layer__cell:nth-child(5) { left: 240%; }
```

Basically I am trying to convert a static code to dynamic code

Comment: change this line       $(targets.eq(i)[0]).css('left', toString(60*i)+  "%")

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code:**

```js
var targets = $('.parallax__layer__cell');
var i ;
 for(i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)
{
  if (targets.eq(i).parents('div.parallax__layer--bg').length) {
          targets.eq(i).css('left', 60*i +  "%");
   }
}
```

```css
.parallax__layer__cell{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parallax__layer--bg">
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">a</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="parallax__layer--bg">
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">b</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax__layer--bg">
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">c</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax__layer--bg">
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">d</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parallax__layer--bg">
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">e</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="parallax__layer__cell">--no parent--</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

What if you put 60 * i into a variable called numPercent and then do numPercent.toString() to convert it to a string?

```
var targets = $('.parallax__layer__cell');
var i = 1;
for(i = 1; i <= targets.length; i++)
{
  if (targets.parents('.parallax__layer--bg').length) {
//apply to only those element that have a parent having class "parallax__layer--bg"
    var numPercent = 60*i;
    targets.eq(i).css('left', numPercent.toString() +  "%");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a timing issue between parallax script and your script. Since css loads first parallax script works fine. But if you remove css and run your script after parallax script it may not do the same effect. Make sure your script runs before actual parallax script.